# React site is really slow and buttons don't work

Tags: reactjs

I've recently created a website using React, I'm new at it so it has some issues.
The website is really slow so it becomes hard to navigate as you can see: https://giacomosorbi.github.io/joanaoli09-module-ii/.
I already resized all images so don't know what to do exactly to fix this.

The second problem I need help with is the buttons that don't redirect to other pages as they are supposed to, you can check on the website. To create the buttons I used `NavLink` inside the `<Button>`:

`<Button variant="outline-dark" onClick={() => (<NavLink to="/products"></NavLink>)}>See our Products</Button>`

I imported the NavLink as I should so I'm not sure what's wrong. This is the whole Homepage but this happens throughout other pages in the site:

```
import React from "react"
import "./HomePage.css";
import  homeImage1 from '../../assets/homeImage1.jpg'
import  homeImage2 from '../../assets/homeImage2.jpg'
import homeImage3 from '../../assets/homeImage3.jpg'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import aboutImage from '../../assets/aboutImage.jpg'

const Home = () => (
    <>
    <div class="homepage">
        <h3>We help you create healthy recipes in a easy and quick way, for a variety of breakfasts and snacks</h3>
        
        <div className="images">
       
            <img src={homeImage1} alt="breakfast bowl"/>
            <img src={homeImage2} alt="breakfast bowl"/>
            <img src={homeImage3} alt="breakfast bowl"/>
        
        </div>
        <div className="presentation">
       We provide easy and beautifully prepared breakfast and snacks for any occasions: a picnic, weekly breakfasts for the kids, a last minute party, or just because you’re feeling like it. 
       <p>We deliver at your house or location. In addition, we also have planned meals for the whole week. We provide the recipes and the ingredients necessary.</p>
       
       <Button variant="outline-dark" onClick={() => (<NavLink to="/products"></NavLink>)}>See our Products</Button>
       </div>
        
                <div className="about-section">
                    
                    <div className="about-image">
                    <img src={aboutImage} alt="about-us"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="about-us">
                    <h1>Want to know  more about us? </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                      <Button variant="outline-dark" className="btn-about" onClick={() => (<NavLink to="/about"></NavLink>)}>Know More</Button>
                    </div>
                    
              </div>
        
        <div className="contact-section">
        <h1> GET IN TOUCH </h1>
        <p>Send us a message regarding your order or other enquiries you might have</p>
        <Button  variant="dark" onClick={() => (<NavLink to="/contact"></NavLink>)}>Contact us!</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
)

export default Home;
```

You can see the whole code here: https://github.com/GiacomoSorbi/joanaoli09-module-ii/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second issue:

`NavLink` is a component, what you want is a function that will redirect you.

Alternatively, you can use the `href` prop of the `Button` component:

```
<Button variant="dark" href="/contact">Contact us!</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `NavLink` in your `onClick` function, because it's a component. You could just wrap your buttons in it:

```
<NavLink to="/products">
    <Button variant="outline-dark">
        See our products
    </Button>
</NavLink>
```